# Some applications don't have title bar and are always on top

Tags: debian, mate-desktop, window-title

Some applications (Konsole, gedit, ...) don't have title bar (so, I can't quit them by clicking on the cross) and stay always on the top when they are opened (I have to minimize them with a keyboard shortcut to hide them).
For instance, when I open gedit, I just have a white screen with a cursor and that's all (I also have the status bar at the bottom if I enable it).

*Note:* the "Always on top" option is not enabled for gedit or Konsole.

Here is a little screenshot when I try to move an application not concerned by this issue ahead of gedit:
[image]
On this screenshot, I was moving my Firefox window to my left screen but I can't because gedit stay on the top.

My desktop environment is MATE Desktop Environment 1.16.2 and I'm using Debian 9:

```
> uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u6 (2018-10-08)
```

What can I do to solve this issue (ie. get title bar back and disable the always on top feature of some apps)?

Comment: What window manager or desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @Gilles MATE Desktop Environment 1.16.2